# Wiring on washing machine lock

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to replace my washing machine (Haier MHS1000TVE) lock (in photo):

[image]

To do so, I have to determine the correct wiring, that is, which one is **Common** (C), which one is **Line** (L) and which one is **Neutral** (N).
I've found this photo in a service manual online:

[image]

According to this scheme, the C is definitely the middle one, but how do I determine the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

C is definately number 2, check for markings on the device. My bet is on it being the one with the red wire (because the diagram shows 2 wires to "C")

for live and neutral measure the resistance from the plug.

Also look at where the wires go compared to the diagram.

But, if forced to guess brown is live and blue is neutral, it's an international colour code.